# Comparing primative booleans in if statements

Tags: java, boolean, comparison

In terms of primitive booleans, what is the difference between

```
if(someBoolean == false){}
```

and

```
if(someBoolean = false){}
```

I wrote the latter (in Eclipse) expecting an error to be thrown but none was.

Comment: in the latter case the value is assigned to the boolean varibale while in the former case the value is compared. When you are using you dont need to use `==` operator. You can directly use `if(someBoolean){}` or `if(!someBoolean){}` for true or false case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`==` is used for comparison

`=` is used for assingnment.

So in your first case you are comparing the values and in the second case you are assigning. Both of the statement will compile and execute successfully.

However if  are looking for an effective way to use that inside an `if` statement then you can simply do as:

```
if(someBoolean)   //for checking true
```

and

```
if(!someBoolean)   //for checking false
```

Comment: I had assumed it was assigning false to someBoolean but was confused since primitive integers cannot be assigned within if statements (retrospectively, I should have realized booleans can be stand-alone arguements). Follow-up: can you think of a situation where this would ever be necessary, or is it a redundant feature?

Answer (score 0):

`someBoolean = false` assigns the value of false to that boolean, rather than actually comparing if it is false or not.

= assigns

== compares

Answer (score 0):

`if(someBoolean=false)` will set false to `someBoolean` then return someBoolean,then if statement judge the someBoolean value,so it will compiles well.

But such code won't compile:

```
int val = 2;
if(val = 3){
}
```

it will compile error:

> InCompatible Types:Required:boolean,Found

because its return value is int,can't be changed to boolean type which if statement needs.

Answer (score 0):

`someBoolean == false` is comparing that returns a boolean value
`someBoolean = false` is assinging that returns a boolean value as well

Answer (score 0):

if(someBoolean = false){}

the above statement first assign the value to the boolean variable and then condition checking is done. There is no error in the statement.

if(someBoolean == false){}

This statement will only do condition checking.